# Python Scrapy - Attaching log files but in zipped format

Tags: python, scrapy

We start several crawlers. If 1 hits an error then an email is sent. The problem is that the log is sometimes too large (they are flat files).

question: how could we zip and attach the files in the easiest way?

Help appreciated

```
except Exception as e:
    from db_tool.settings import IS_DEV

    if not IS_DEV:
        from scrapy_app.settings import EMAIL_TO, LOG_DIR
        from django.template.loader import render_to_string
        from scrapy_app.utils import send_email
        import os

        logging.exception("exception occured while starting the spider. sending admins email")
        for user_email in EMAIL_TO:
            email_subject = f'sohb2bcrawler: General error encountered. Crawler did not finish '
            email_message = render_to_string('general_error.html')
            send_email(email_subject, email_message, email_to=user_email, files=[os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'log_info.log'), os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'log_error.log')])
    else:
        logging.exception("exception occured while starting the spider.")
```

Comment: see [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#module-zipfile)

Comment: Thanks. Could we issue the zip, attachment and cleanup of the zip (all dynamic and auto cleanup) in 1 statement? Instead of coding a create, then attach, then remove zip def? Said otherwise, prevent `with ZipFile('spam.zip', 'w') as myzip:
    myzip.write('eggs.txt')` in another code statement